# CSV File Generation for Selenium Test Cases

Tags: csv, selenium, testing, automation, testng

Is there any way for generating a CSV file which can store the test case results of all selenium scripts. Either Test Case Pass or Test Case Fail.I am using TestNG for Executing the Selenium Test Cases.

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work with us? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG then it's straight forward to see number of test cases pass or fail by looking into output folder like :

```
\workspace\proj_name\test-output\index.html
```

It gives itself all detail description for test cases.

Still if you want to write your results to file then you can refer following link:

http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-web-driver-menu/selenium-test-automation-with-java/167-write-selenium-webdriver-testng-result-to-excel-file

Hope it will help you.